# Как правильно написать селектор?

Tags: css

[image]

Нужно дотянуться до этого элемента, но мой селектор не работает:

```
.big_login input[name="authenticity_token"]
```

Как правильно дотянуться до этого элемента, с учетом того, что он находится именно в элементе с классом `.big_login`

Т.к. таких форм на сайте много, а мне нужно достать токен именно из этой формы.

Answer (score 3):

Это не класс big_login а идентификатор, нужно обращаться 
`#big_login input[name="authenticity_token"]`

Comment: Не заметил ;) Опять глупая ошибка